# MS SQL Db Mail Sent Status always Unsent

Tags: sql-server-2016, sp-send-dbmail

Attempting to set up Database mail on a SQL 2016 instance, have run through the set up process and added all the relevant info however the emails aren't being sent. They just sit saying "unsent".

I've gone over and over and over different authentications, adding users here, adding users there...

[image]

Comment: if you try and send a test email, what error do you get? Right click on Database Mail under the Management folder and click Send Test Email

Comment: no error, it all goes through fine but then just sits as unsent.

Answer (score 2):

OK, i'm posting my own answer in case anyone else hits this same issue, I had to install .net 3.5 on the windows 2012 server in order to execute DB mail items. This is despite not being part of SQL 2016's requirements! Installing it was a nightmare as well..

[Installing .net 3.5 on Server 2012 Here](http://jackstromberg.com/2014/08/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-server-2012-and-windows-server-2012-r2/)

Comment: lol installing it shouldn't have been hard. 3.5 is an older version so if you had a later version I would have been suprised.